# Rude/abusive comment left on a now-deleted question; what can be done about it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deletion, comments

Earlier this morning, I came across [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45242/did-trump-mean-ancient-rome). As well as multiple downvotes, it had attracted a comment consisting of a rather blunt answer followed by "Do your homework". I responded suggesting that the commenter post an actual answer instead of a condescending remark.

The question was put on hold before they could do so, but a few minutes ago I received the following in my inbox:

[image: A screenshot of an inbox message, informing me of a comment reading "@F1Krazy - et voila...fuck the user and their question"]

...and when I checked, the question had been deleted.

While the question may have been low-quality, this is still straight-up rude and abusive, and a flagrant violation of the CoC. But since I don't have 10k rep, I can't even see who posted this comment, let along flag it. I assume it was the user who posted the initial condescending remark, but the timing and wording suggest the question was deleted by whoever posted this comment, and the user in question doesn't have that privilege.

**What should be done about this comment?** Or since the question has been deleted, should *anything* be done about it? I personally don't think people should be allowed to break the CoC in comments and get away with it just because the thing they commented on was deleted, but I'd like to get a community consensus on this.

Comment: [Related](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4452/44766)?

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl I believe so, yes.

Comment: flag as rude, you don't even need mods to fix this stuff :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz The entire point of this Meta question is that I *can't* flag that comment, because the question it was on was deleted immediately after it was posted, and I don't have 10k rep here.

Comment: If you can't see it, why does it matter? It's up to 10k users to do the deed

Comment: I think probably the best bet is to not worry about it.  The post was put on hold by 5 members of the site, 2 of which were 10K+ plus members.  While it is abusive, it won't appear to anyone outside of the 10K+ users who can see deleted posts, and we see much worse things than that daily.

Comment: @Sklivvz It matters because this isn't merely an unnecessary comment, but a rather crass personal attack. The CoC recommends a warning or temporary suspension (if it's considered harassment, which the comment arguably might be). If a warning isn't issued, it will make it more difficult to identify a pattern of repeated violations, which will make it more difficult to rein these sorts of comments in.

Comment: 10k users can take care of 10k content, I think that's on purpose :-) In any case, flag it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from your screenshot has been deleted (which happened before I even saw it), so you don't need to do anything more.

If this happens again, you (as a <10k user) can flag one of your own posts as "in need of moderator intervention", give a link to the post/comment and say that you think the comment should be deleted since it is rude. 10k+ users can just visit the deleted post and flag directly with the standard flag. (I would only do this for rude comments, as I don't think it really matters for other comments, like obsolete ones.)

This will allow the matter to be resolved privately.

---

Note: I believe that the one comment was deleted with a single flag because it contained a bad word (i.e. "fuck"), as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284053/323179). However, for comments that are rude but don't contain any bad words or phrases, deleting the parent post causes all pending comment flags under it to be [marked helpful while leaving the comments up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280413/323179) for anyone with sufficient privileges to see. (In fact, this happened to my comment flag, unfortunately.)

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: It was nuked by me as my last act as a mod

Comment: @Sklivvz Going out with a bang ;)